# Using the Environ function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Two things; I would like to know how to use the 'Environ' function to know what the name of my user name is and then I would like to use an if statement using the  'Environ' function to instruct my database to perform certain actions. Below is a simple if statement which I am trying to run (assuming my computer name is 'XXX').   Unfortunately, i am getting the error message 'Argument not optional'.

```
    If Environ = xxx Then
     MsgBox = vbOK

   Else

     MsgBox = vbRetry

   End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user the environ function to find the username domain-name

for example `environ("username")` will give you the username of the person logged in.

```
If Environ("username") = "xxx" Then
 MsgBox = vbOK

 Else

 MsgBox = vbRetry

 End If
```

Comment: Thanks Izzy, but I am getting an error message that the returned value needs to be a variant or an object.  This is my codePrivate Sub Comando147_Click()

      If Environ("username") = "Andrea LENTI" Then
      MsgBox = vbOK

      Else

      MsgBox = vbRetry

      End If
    End Sub

Comment: Please could you try msgbox environ("username") and let me know what u see also can you try msgbox "ok" instead of msgbox vbok

Comment: Thanks Izzy, you got it!  Just a question though, why do the standard message boxes (e.g. vbok) not work with this logic?

Comment: vbok is a type of messagebox rather than a response. For example you can use Msgbox "Some Message", vbyesno / vbok and depending on that the user will get buttons for instance vbok would give only one button - "Ok" and vbyesno would give "yes" and "no" button